# Does Loop Protect Protocol work with Port-Security?

Tags: security, port-security, aruba

I'm working for a company which wants to change its network equipment.

We are changing old aruba by aruba 6100. We are also changing network link, we remove network interconnection and we connect the switches to two network cores with fibres.

We don't need STP anymore, so I'm configuring Loop-Protect on every switches to prevent network Loop. I also want to increase the network security by implanting Mac port-Secuirty.

The problem is when I configure Port-Security on every port, Loop-Protect doesnt detect any loop anymore. When I disable Port-Security, it works again.

My conclusion is that Loop-Protection doesn't work with Port-Security, is that normal ?

Update : i wanted to test loop protection with STP BPDU Guard. It works well, like Loop-Protect. But same thing, when I use port-access port-security enable, loops are no more detected. It feels like port-security is locking every loop detection protocol

Comment: I don’t know Aruba equipment very well, but I don’t see any reason to turn off STP.

Comment: Why would I let it ON if I don't have any interconnection.

Comment: I, as well, don’t know Aruba gear that well, and I’m just as confused about why you don’t think you should use STP. There are very few scenarios that justify not using it, so I’m interested to know what yours is.

Comment: I'm using LACp to connect my switch to the core, the only thing that could interest me in STP would be Loop Protection, which his 1 of the mutiple STP function. Or I could just use Loop-Protection which is a Protocol make only for this.

Comment: @Netexis There are several other benefits of using STP. There’s loop protection, of course, but there’s also root protection, BPDU guard, making certain VLANs the roots on specific switches that may be where certain systems are at, shortening the path, etc.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

By logic, port-level security makes active loop detection pretty much gratuitous. Loop detection is designed to detect and disable loops created by accident or maliciously - both are very hard (if not impossible) to accomplish with proper port-level security.

However, I'd recommend leaving RSTP/MSTP *en*abled as it doesn't hurt and can save you one day. Just secure access ports with Root Guard, TCN Guard and optionally BPDU Guard to avoid network disruptions.

The only drawback of STP vs (probe) loop detection is that STP cannot detect remote loops behind intermediate switches which filter BPDUs and don't participate in STP. Otherwise it should be considered as generally superior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I guess i'm goint to let RSTP on switches... When I enable port-security, it dosent detect loops, I don't think thats normal that loop protect dosent work when port-security is enable.

Comment: @Netexis Have you attempted to contact Aruba support to make sure this is expected behavior?

Comment: That's what I am going to do, I want to be sure thats not a bug

Comment: I guess it's intentional since it doesn't make too much sense. Needs to be documented properly, but that's not really HPE's strong side...

Comment: @Zac67 Yeah, that’s for sure. I haven’t dealt with them in a while but from what I recall documentations were either never made or were very bare (like basically a whole doc to say “yep, that sure is an error.  Good luck”.)

Comment: loop protect is for protection against devices that does not participate in STP domain like unmanaged switches (hence no BPDUs from that devices). Imagine you have an unmanaged switch that is connected to Aruba switch from port 8. This switch has 16 ports and somehow somebody created a loop in this switch. STP of aruba won't be able to handle this. loop protect mechanism will do. It will send a certain code for a check from its ports, if the switch receives the same packet back from the port, it will decide that there is a loop and disable the port.

Comment: @kayaatabey Most unmanaged switches don't comply to 802.1D, so they forward BPDUs, making them transparent for STP. Having a managed switch *not* participating in STP and having a loop behind that is a real danger, yes. With MAC port security any switch requires a permitted node connected to it to work in any case. Loop protection works across ports as well.